# Induction with Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, induction, binomial-coefficients

If $k\geq 0$ and $k\leq\frac{n-1}{2}$, then prove that $$\binom{n}{k}\leq \binom{n}{k+1}$$.

Then prove there is equality only if $k=\frac{n-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0\leq k\leq\frac{n-1}{2} \implies 2k \leq n-1 \implies k+1 \leq n-k \implies \frac{1}{ n-k} \leq \frac{1}{1+k}$

$$\frac{1}{ n-k} \leq \frac{1}{1+k} \implies \frac{n!}{ (n-k)k!(n-k-1)!} \leq \frac{n!}{(1+k)k!(n-k-1)!} \\ \implies \binom{n}{k}\leq \binom{n}{k+1}$$

Equality can be verified very easily.

Just put $k=\frac{n-1}{2}$ in the binomial coefficient to see that they are equal.

Comment: Ok, so the first line is the first part, and the rest is to prove equality?

Comment: can you please explain i did not understand

Comment: Did you prove the equality in the above answer?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
r_k
&=\dfrac{ \binom{n}{k+1}}{\binom{n}{k}}\\
&=\dfrac{ \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}}{\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}\\
&=\dfrac{ k!(n-k)!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}\\
&=\dfrac{n-k}{k+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$r_k \le 1
\iff
n-k \ge k+1
\iff k \le \frac{n-1}{2}
$
with equality
if and only of
$k = \frac{n-1}{2}
$.